# Keras: do `sample weights` take part in the derivatives

Tags: neural-network, keras, training, loss-function

According to [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit), `sample_weight` can be used in order to give any sample in the training data a different importance in the loss.

I have googled around but have not found the answer to my question as follows:

- Do `sample weights` take part in the derivatives? In other words, does Keras use these weights to train the model or they just give rise to a different loss value? i.e., the derivatives are "still" computed w.r.t. to the "unweighted" loss?

Because the loss function is not actually defined based on the sample weights, its rather passed in (as an argument) to the `fit` function in Keras.

Comment: These weights don't take part as derivatives because these are constants.; These just help in loss balancing and the backprop that follows is accordingly

Answer (score 5):

`sample_weights` affect the `total_loss`, which is used to calculate the gradients.

> Because the loss function is not actually defined based on the sample weights, its rather passed in (as an argument) to the fit function in Keras

I think that what you're missing is that the loss function actually [returns a list of loss values (one per sample in the batch)](https://keras.io/api/losses/#creating-custom-losses). This is precisely because during fit, it is multiplied by the `sample_weight` of that batch.

Please note that although "[class based](https://keras.io/api/losses/#usage-of-losses-with-compile-amp-fit)" losses support reduction (over the batch), the `Loss` base class implements the weighting during reduction.